# Push new key/value to state with hooks - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to push a pair of key/value (from 2 inputs) into an existing state with hooks.

Here is my JSX :

```
<div className="mt-2 text-left flex flex-wrap">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label htmlFor="newIncomeName"></label>
                            <input className="w-32 border italic p-1 text-gray-500 text-xs" id="newIncomeName"
                                name="newIncomeName"
                                type="text"
                            />

                            <label htmlFor="newIncomeAmount"></label>
                            <input className="w-32 border italic p-1 text-gray-500 text-xs" id="newIncomeAmount"
                                name="newIncomeAmount"
                                type="number"
                            />
                        </fieldset>
                        <button onClick={handleAddIncome}>
                            <i className="fas fa-check text-gray-400 hover:text-green-500 text-xs mt-1 p-1"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Here is my function :

```
  const handleAddIncome = () => {
        let incomeName = document.getElementById('newIncomeName').value
        let incomeAmount = document.getElementById('newIncomeAmount').value
        let data = [
            [incomeName], incomeAmount
        ]
        setUserWalletIncomes({ ...userWalletIncomes, data })
}
```

As you can see, I wish the `incomeName` to be the key, and `incomeAmount` to be the value.

My actual state look like this :

```
{income1: 1300, income2: 1300, income3: 1300, incometest: 400}
```

My function doesn't work, it create a key named "data" and the amount does not react well. On the first click, it pushes well but on second click, it erase the last push, instead of adding a new one.

I'm new with hooks. Thanks for help

Comment: Can you share more code where use defined hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change data to an object:

```
let data = {
  [incomeName]: incomeAmount
}

setUserWalletIncomes({ ...userWalletIncomes, ...data })
```

Comment: It works  Thank you. Why is the spread operator necessary with ```data``` here ?

Comment: Because `data` also an object. You need  to use spread operator  to merge object `userWalletIncomes` and object `data ` to a new object